# Running terminal command in swift doesn't work

Tags: swift, macos, bash, command, nstask

I'm trying to check if a `brew` command is available using `command -v brew`. Example output in terminal:

```
MacBook-Air-USER:~ USER$ command -v brew 
/usr/local/bin/brew
```

I'm using this code:

```
func runCommand(command cmd : String) -> Array<String> {
    var result : Array<String> = []

    let task = NSTask()
    task.launchPath = "/bin/bash"
    task.arguments = (["-c", cmd])

    let pipe = NSPipe()
    task.standardOutput = pipe
    let handle = pipe.fileHandleForReading
    handle.waitForDataInBackgroundAndNotify()

    let errPipe = NSPipe()
    task.standardError = errPipe
    let errHandle = errPipe.fileHandleForReading
    errHandle.waitForDataInBackgroundAndNotify()

    var startObserver : NSObjectProtocol!
    startObserver = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName(NSFileHandleDataAvailableNotification, object: nil, queue: nil) { notification -> Void in
        let data = handle.availableData
        if data.length > 0 {
            if let output = String(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
                print("Output : \(output)")
                result.append(output)
            }
        }
        else {
            print("EOF on stdout")
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(startObserver)
        }
    }

    var endObserver : NSObjectProtocol!
    endObserver = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName(NSTaskDidTerminateNotification, object: nil, queue: nil) {
    notification -> Void in
        print("Task terminated with code \(task.terminationStatus)")
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(endObserver)
    }

    var errObserver : NSObjectProtocol!
    errObserver = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName(NSTaskDidTerminateNotification, object: nil, queue: nil) {
    notification -> Void in
        let data = errHandle.availableData
        if (data.length > 0) {
            if let output = String(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
                print("Error : \(output)")
                result.append(output)

                NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(errObserver)
            }
        }
    }

    task.launch()
    task.waitUntilExit()
    return result
}
```

And running it like this:

```
let arr = runCommand(command: "command -v brew")
```

And the array is always empty - I can't get any output. How to solve this problem?

UPD: The same happens if I try `which brew` command

UPD2: It works only with built-in commands, such as `ls`, but doesn't work with ones like `brew` or `tor`

Comment: I don't have Brew on my computer, but when I tried `let arr = runCommand(command: "which ls")` it ran ok

Comment: @CodeDifferent, actually, it runs only with built-in commands, but not with ones like tor or brew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$PATH` of the instance of `bash` created to run the command may not  be set. One way round this would be to specify an explicit path for the command:

```
runCommand(command: "command -v /usr/local/bin/brew")
```